# Sending and receiving a struct in Contiki - Dealing with pointers and structs

Tags: c, pointers, contiki

I'm making a simple program at the moment which is attempting to send a struct across a network using contiki. I have a function which is called on receiving a transmission, and a function called for transmitting.

The **struct** is defined as follows:

```
 struct metadata {
    int values[5];
 };
 struct metadata packet;
 int max_val = 100;
 int min_val = 1;
 int random_val = random_rand();
 if(random_val < 0)
 {
   random_val *= -1;
 }

 int proposal_value = (random_val % max_val) + min_val;

 int index = node_id - 1;
 packet.values[index] = proposal_value;
```

**Transmitting function:**

```
static void trickle_tx(void *ptr, uint8_t suppress)
{
  uip_ipaddr_copy(&trickle_conn->ripaddr, &ipaddr);
  uip_udp_packet_send(trickle_conn, &packet, sizeof(packet));

  /* Restore to 'accept incoming from any IP' */
  uip_create_unspecified(&trickle_conn->ripaddr);

  leds_off(LEDS_RED);
}
```

**The following code is for a `tcpip_handler` function which is called when a mote receives a transmission.**

As far as I'm aware, I'm sending out `&packet` which is the memory address of my packet struct. Upon receiving, I want the data within this struct, so first need to access the memory location. So I create a variable `received_struct` of type `struct metadata` as so:
**First approach**:

```
   if(uip_newdata()) {
    struct metadata received_struct;
    received_struct = (struct metadata) *uip_appdata;
    int data[5];

    data = received_struct.values;
   }
```

**Error**:

```
proposer.c:120:31: error: invalid use of void expression
proposer.c:123:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[5]’ from type ‘int *
```

**SECOND APPROACH**:
So from here I tried an alternate approach where i cast the received packet to a metadata pointer. I then assign `received_struct` to be the pointer to `received_struct`. At this point I figure `received_struct` is now in its 'normal' format, not a pointer neither an address. However this fails to work as well.

```
 if(uip_newdata()) {
    struct metadata* received_struct_ptr;
    received_struct_ptr = (struct metadata*) uip_appdata;
    struct metadata received_struct;
    received_struct = *received_struct_ptr;
    int data[5];

    data = received_struct.values;
    }
```

**ERROR:**

> proposer.c:125:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type
>   ‘int[5]’ from type ‘int *’

**APPROACH 3:**
For this approach I cast the incoming data to a `metdata` pointer, I then retrieve the given struct pointed to by this and assign it to `data_struct` and attempt to access the data.

```
  if(uip_newdata()) {
    struct metadata* struct_pointer;
    struct_pointer = (struct metadata*) uip_appdata;
    struct metadata data_struct;
    data_struct = *struct_pointer;
    int data [5];

    data = &data_struct.values;
```

**ERROR**:

```
proposer.c:125:10: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘int[5]’ from type ‘int (*)[5]’
```

To be honest, I've really no idea what's going on here. I thought it would be as simple as taking the pointer to the memory address, getting the struct and accessing it, but this isn't happening. I thought I did, but it seems I don't understand pointers fully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer. An array can *decay* to a pointer to its first element (i.e. `someArray` decays to `&someArray[0]`). You can't assign to an array, but you can [*copy*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on the right track with your second approach.

```
received_struct_ptr = (struct metadata*) uip_appdata;
struct metadata received_struct;
received_struct = *received_struct_ptr;
int data[5];
```

You have cast the pointer to the correct type, and assigned the received data to a structure. But there's no built-in feature in the C language to assign every member of an array to another array, so you need to do it by hand:

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<5; ++i)
{
    data[i] = received_struct.values[i];
}
```

Note, though, that `data` isn't really any more accessible or useful than `received_struct.values`, and you've introduced another number `5` into the code. That could be a problem if the size of the array changes in future. So, all things considered, you might be better off just accessing that data directly (`int final_value = received_struct.values[4];`) rather than making a copy.